# Command for Package feature Demo (listings problem)

Tags: listings

I have to write a small demonstration of some features of my package. I was thinking about doing something like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\demo}[1]{%
    \fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    #1
    \end{minipage}}%
    \fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \begin{lstlisting}
    #1
    \end{lstlisting}
    \end{minipage}}
}

\begin{document}

\demo{\section{section}}

\end{document}
```

But this isn't working, because of listings can't be used inside commands. Any nice solution? (Would like to have a left right comparison between source and result)

And is there some way to enclose this so that nothing outside is affected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use and set the listings parameter in the usual way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\begin{document}

\begin{LTXexample}[width=0.5\linewidth]
\section{section}
\end{LTXexample}

\end{document}
```

[image]